# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'

Tags: python, chatterbot

I just installed `chatterbot` last time with CMD, installation was successful, but keeps throwing me `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Last time i modified the System variables in path, adding the `python37/scripts` rute. Now i tried but with the rute: `C:\Python27\Scripts`. It throws me this exception on CMD when i try to install it:

```
>Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='c:\\users\\arcanet\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-
wejd5c\\murmurhash\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
c:\users\arcanet\appdata\local\temp\pip-w1n8yf-record\
install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in 
c:\users\arcanet\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-wejd5c\murmurhash\
```

I tried to upgrade python´s setuptools but didn't work and also tried `pip install murmurhash` but throws the same error. I hope you can help.

Comment: The failure on Python 2.7 isn't really with `murmurhash`. It's with `blis`. For Python 3.7 there is a wheel with a Windows binary for `blis`. But for Python 2.7 there isn't, and `pip` tries to build it from source. Only, the `blis` build specifies `clang` as the C compiler and it is *really unlikely* that you would have that on a Windows machine. So the compile of `blis` fails because `clang` isn't there. You are seeing a failure on `murmurhash` because it needs `blis`. I hesitate to recommend that you try building `clang` from source. I can only suggest you stick with Python 3.7.

Comment: @BoarGules ¿how can I run a Python file with Python 3.7? I use `python file.py` for example, but I think that command use python 2.7 by default.

Comment: You can install several versions of Python on the same machine. They live happily side-by-side. For example, I have Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7 installed. Just go to `python.org` and download the appropriate version. Choose 64-bit unless your machine can't handle 64-bit. Choose 64 bit or 32 bit, not both: endless trouble otherwise. Be aware that you have to install *every single* 3rd-party library afresh. Use `pip` for that. `pip` lives in the `Scripts` subdirectory of every Python installation. Under no circumstances try to take shortcuts and copy libraries from other versions of Python.